# SharePoint Online search not pulling any new sites created

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, crawling, modern-team-site, index

So it seems like when our users try to search for sites in SharePoint Online that have been created in the past week or so, it does not show up under the SharePoint search bar?

Here is a site I created titled Debug and I did a search for it from our homepage and it does not show up.

[image: Seach does not pull up site]

I also checked the crawling log for this site and this is what I got:

ErrorCode                    : -2147217992

ErrorDesc                    :

ErrorCount                   : 13

What do think could be causing this issue and what steps should I take to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click **Organization** and search under organization search page.
[image]